# How to fix/stick an header row on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, header

i would like to fix/stick the header "top" row (NOT middle and bottom rows) during the scroll of the page. I also created a class for the top row. This is my header code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFqqN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add your code in the questions and do not paste the link to a screenshot. It would help to get better and faster answers, if you also add your css code, because the styling is done within the stylesheet.

But I think I got your problem.

---

If your header is at the top of your page, it is a simple css property you add to your class in the stylesheet:

```
.riga_sup {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

Take a look at the example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_fixed_menu

---

If your header is not at the top of your page, but you want it to be fixed if it is at the top position after scrolling, you will need a little bit of javascript to add the class with the "position: fixed;" styling when the scroll reaches the the element. In the example the header has a ID of "myHeader".

```
<script>
    window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
    var header = document.getElementById("header");
    var sticky = header.offsetTop;
    function myFunction() {
      if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
          header.classList.add("sticky");
      } else {
          header.classList.remove("sticky");
      }
    }
</script>
```

In your CSS you give the properties to the "sticky" class:

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

Here is an example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried your codes (JS and CSS) but do not work...

Comment: Please add your css code so we can have a look. And copy the code of your screenshot. This really will help you get better answers.

Comment: You can paste just the parts with the classes and ids of the header markup you show in the screenshot. Also the code in the screenshot is not too long ;)